# I have this error "ParserError: Expected '(' but got identifier" need some help

Tags: solidity

This is my code but it has the following error

```
ParserError: Expected '(' but got identifier
--> contracts/Kim Il Sung Coin.sol:17:14:
|
17 | function balanceOf(address owner) public view returns(uint) {
| ^^^^^^^^^
```

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.11;
/// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
contract KimIlSungCoin{
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) public allowance;
    uint public totalSupply = 100000000000000 * 10 **14;
    string public name = "Kim Il Sung";
    string public symbol = "KIMIL";
    uint public decimals = 14;
    
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner,address indexed spender,uint value);
    
    constructor() public{
        balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;

    function balanceOf(address owner) public view returns(uint) {
        return balances[owner];
    }
    
    function transfer(address to, uint value)public returns(bool){
        require(balanceOf(msg.sender) >= value, 'balance too low');
        balances[to] += value;
        balances[msg.sender] -= value;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
        return true;
    }
    
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) public returns(bool){
        require(balanceOf(from) >= value, 'balance too low');
        require(allowance[from][msg.sender] >= value, 'allowance too low');
        balances[to] += value;
        balances[from] -= value;
        emit Transfer(from, to , value);
        return true;
    }
    function approve(address spender, uint value) public returns(bool){
        allowance[msg.sender][spender] = value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
        return true;
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing closing bracket in the constructor

```js
constructor() public{
        balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
} // this is missing
```